# Loops in C - for() or while() - which is BEST?

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

for() or while() - which is BEST?

```
for (i=1; i<a; i++)
  /* do something */
```

OR

```
i=1;
while (i<a) {
/* do something */
i++;
}
```

Comment: Depends. Do you have `continue;` as a part of `/* do something */`?  Then the loops don't even do the same thing.

Comment: Best in what sense?

Comment: Surely, this is the definition of a *subjective* question.

Comment: @pavium: Not really; the community has standard idioms and best practices.

Comment: @Jason, well I can see it wasn't argumentative (and no-one voted to close it down).

Comment: If you have only two idioms, you can't have a best, only a better :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first is the idiomatic way; it is what most C coders will expect to see. However, I should note that most people will also expect to see

```
for(i = 0; i < a; i++)
```

Note that the loop starts at zero. This will do something `a` times. If you're going to  write a `while` loop that is equivalent to a `for` loop as above I strongly encourage you to write it as a `for` loop. Again, it is what C coders expect to see. Further, as a `for` loop it is easier to read as everything (initialization, loop condition, expression to be executed after each iteration) are all on one line. For the `while` loop they are spread out hindering readability.

Note, however, there are circumstances in which seemingly equivalent `for` and `while` loops are actually not. For example:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if(i == 5) continue;
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

and

```
i = 0;
while(i < 10) {
    if(i == 5) continue;
    printf("%d\n", i);
    i++;
}
```

appear at first glance to be equivalent but they are not. The `for` loop will print `0--9` skipping `5` on the console whereas the `while` loop will print `0--4` on the console and then enter an infinite loop.

Now, that handles the simple case that you asked about. What about the more complex cases that you didn't ask about? Well, it really depends but a good rule of thumb is this: if you are going to repeat something a fixed pre-determined number of times, a `for` loop is generally best. Otherwise, use a `while` loop. This is not a hard-and-fast rule but it is a good rule-of-thumb. For example, you could write

```
unsigned int v;
unsigned int c;
for(c = 0; v; v >>= 1) c += v & 1;
```

but I think most C programmers would write this as

```
unsigned int v;
unsigned int c;
c = 0;
while(v) { c += v & 1; v >>= 1; }
```

Or, as another example, if you're going to read until the end of a file then you should use a `while` loop. Thus

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(path, "r");
while(fgets(buf, max, fp) != NULL) { /* something */ }
```

instead of

```
FILE *fp;
for(fp = fopen(path, "r"); fgets(buf, max, fp) != NULL; ) { /* something */ }
```

Now, reaching into religious territory, this is why I prefer `while(1)` as the right way to do an infinite loop over `for(;;)`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

It depends. What makes the reading most easy should be a guideline IMHO. If you know bounds beforehand you probably should use 'for'. Because it clearly says in one line where the looping starts, it ends and how to go from one element to the other.

Answer (score 2):

Vote up for Dan McG - if the loop has a fixed count, etc., use for - it's more idiomatic.   Classic cases of each:

```
for (i = 0; i < THRESHOLD; ++i) {
  something;
}
```

Vs.

```
while (foo->next) {
  foo = foo -> next; 
}
```

Also: if you find yourself leaving out conditions in your for, consider what it would be like if you reworte it as a while.

At the end of the day: go back and read each version of the loop.  Which one stands out more in your mind as "clear" in intent?

Answer (score 1):

Which one makes most sense in the situation.

The `for` loop tells you it is most probably a fixed count loop. Starting at 1 ending before a.

The `while` loop doesn't imply any such thing, just that it ends once `i >= a` (at least from just reading the `while (i<a){` at the top).

Of course, this isn't a rule and programmers generally do as they see fit, but it does make it easy to read through code without having to backtrack to comprehend some section.