# When implementing an infinite loop, is there a difference in using while(1) vs for(;;) vs goto (in C)?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, goto, while-loop

When implementing an infinite loop, is there a difference in using `while(1)` vs `for(;;)` vs `goto`?

Thanks,
Chenz

Comment: I always use while.  I see no point in a for loop constructed in such a way.  That's just a personal preference.  (It appears to me to be missing information, while the while loop looks (to me) more aesthetically pleasing)

Comment: technically, the 1 in the while is a condition which should be tested at each iteration. I do believe all common compilers are smart enough to make a jump out of that one that, rather than a conditional one. Aside from that, they're all equivalent except for style.

Comment: Which infinite loop is faster than the other ?

Comment: Dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242646/loops-in-c-for-or-while-which-is-best

Comment: Using `for(;;)` allows you to `#define ever (;;)` and use `for ever {...` ;)

Comment: +1 for KennyTM for this great #define

Comment: nitpick for @Neil: this is a semi-dupe.  The question you linked talks about `while()` and `for()` in general.  This question's about infinite loops.

Comment: @KennyTM: This is funny and on the other hand misleading. Usually a "infinite" loop doesn't actually last forever but until it is "break"-ed.

Comment: @chiccodoro `#define indefinitely for(;;)` `indefinitely {}`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

They are equivalent, even if you turn the optimizer off.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void f(void) {
    while(1) {
        putchar(' ');
    }
}

extern void g(void) {
    for(;;){
        putchar(' ');
    }
}

extern void h(void) {
    z:
        putchar(' ');
    goto z;
}
```

Compile with `gcc -O0` gives equivalent assembly for all 3 functions:

```
 f:
 ;  [ EXTERNAL ]
 ;
 +00000 00000fb4 80402DE9             stmdb             sp!,{r7,lr}
 +00004 00000fb8 00708DE2             add               r7,sp,#0x0
 +00008 00000fbc 2000A0E3 loc_000008: mov               r0,#0x20
 +0000c 00000fc0 0A0000EB             bl                putchar (stub)
 +00010 00000fc4 FCFFFFEA             b                 loc_000008
 ;
 ;
 g:
 ;  [ EXTERNAL ]
 ;
 +00000 00000fc8 80402DE9             stmdb             sp!,{r7,lr}
 +00004 00000fcc 00708DE2             add               r7,sp,#0x0
 +00008 00000fd0 2000A0E3 loc_000008: mov               r0,#0x20
 +0000c 00000fd4 050000EB             bl                putchar (stub)
 +00010 00000fd8 FCFFFFEA             b                 loc_000008
 ;
 ;
 h:
 ;  [ EXTERNAL ]
 ;
 +00000 00000fdc 80402DE9             stmdb             sp!,{r7,lr}
 +00004 00000fe0 00708DE2             add               r7,sp,#0x0
 +00008 00000fe4 2000A0E3 loc_000008: mov               r0,#0x20
 +0000c 00000fe8 000000EB             bl                putchar (stub)
 +00010 00000fec FCFFFFEA             b                 loc_000008
```

Comment: What command was used to produce this specific assembly output from the object file?

Comment: @bzeaman See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67717002/1599699) for more information on how to do this for g++ and clang++ and how to add comments so that you know which part of the assembly to look at...

Answer (score 9):

I just compared the unoptimized assembler output of gcc:

```
# cat while.c 
int main() {
    while(1) {};
    return 0;
}

# cat forloop.c 
int main() {
    for (;;) { };
    return 0;
}
```

Make assembler output:

```
# gcc -S while.c 
# gcc -S forloop.c
```

Compare assembler files:

```
# diff forloop.s while.s
1c1
<   .file   "forloop.c"
---
>   .file   "while.c"
```

As you can see there are no significant differences. Here is the output

```
# cat while.s 
    .file   "while.c"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
.L2:
    jmp .L2                    # this is the loop in both cases
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.4.3"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

While this is not a technical proof that they are the same, I'd say it is in 99.9% of the cases.

Answer (score 5):

There is hardly any difference in generated assembly. It's more of an stylistic issue:

**Goto** - just ooogly: jumps backward, no explicit infinite block

**while(1)** - better, requires "dummy" condition though and you'll be often warned by compiler(warning level 4) or static analysis tool

**for(;;)** might not be the prettiest, but imho fits best because this construct cannot have any other meaning (compared to while). But some other people prefer while(1) for the "same" reason...

Answer (score 4):

Although there's no significant difference as mentioned in the other posts, a common reason to use `for (;;)` instead of `while (1)` is that static analysis tools (and some compilers with certain warning levels) often complain about the while loop.

Goto is a bit nasty, but should produce the same code as the others.  Personally, I stick to `for (;;)` (to keep Lint happy), but I have no problem with `while (1)`.

Answer (score 4):

`while(1)` and `for(;;)` are exactly equivalent and both are well-understood idioms to code infinite loops.

I would avoid the use of `goto`: to break from an infinite loop or to proceed to the next iteration, use `break` and `continue`.

Answer (score 3):

None. Use what is the most readable to you

Answer (score 2):

In C, `true` is implemented as follows (depending on compiler)

```
#define TRUE 1
```

or

```
#define TRUE (-1)
```

AND false is implemented as

```
#define FALSE 0
```

so `while (1)` is equivalent to `while (true)` since 0 is considered false.

the `while (1) == for (; ;)` as there are no stopping condition.

which is translated to assembler as

```
:loop
  ...
  ...
  ...
  goto loop
```

so if the assembler code doesn't have a `ret` or `exit` instruction, it's considered a infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

From what I recall of my "disassembling years", it won't make much a difference (compilers are *smart* enough). It is more about aesthetics IMO.