# Double semi colon ( ; ; ) allowed in C#.net?

Tags: c#, .net

I accidentally put two semi colon at the end of a statement while writing some code. I was amazed that it didn't gave any error. I mean what is the purpose of allowing double semi colon? What it actually means and how it can be useful at any particular programming method?

Comment: `;;` means an empty statement. Empty statements are meaningless, but still treated as a correct code from the C# compiler

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374569/c-sharp-empty-statement

Comment: https://twitter.com/peterritchie/status/534011965132120064 ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `;` is just an empty statement in other words [null statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7zyw61x.aspx). It's usually useless but completely valid.

This is used in loops where you want to perform something repeatedly but do not want to add a loop body.As shown in the below example:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 10; line[i++] = 0 )
 ;
```

In your case however, first semicolon is the end of the statement, second one is the empty statement.Which is useless and will be ignored by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

`;;` is just the end of a statement, followed by an empty statement. Just like Oracle supports `null;`. And other platforms do the same.

Sometimes you don't want to perform an action when you are supposed to according to the specs, like in a `if`, `while`, etc.

```
if (SomeAction())
  ;
else
  SomethingElse();
```

Which of course should be written as:

```
if (!SomeAction())
  SomethingElse();
```

It is probably easier to support `;;` as an statement end following an empty statement in general than support all the specific scenarios where you want to allow it.

Comment: It certainly is useful, see the linked questions

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Agreed.