# Should I use `while (true)` or `for (;;)` (in languages that support both)?

Tags: for-loop, while-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When implementing an infinite loop, is there a difference in using while(1) vs for(;;) vs goto (in C)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288856/when-implementing-an-infinite-loop-is-there-a-difference-in-using-while1-vs-fo)

In languages where `while (true)` or `for (;;)` both mean "loop forever", which should I use?

Comment: It sounds like this has been covered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288856/when-implementing-an-infinite-loop-is-there-a-difference-in-using-while1-vs-fo, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885908/while-1-vs-for-is-there-a-speed-difference, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379246/any-reason-to-replace-whilecondition-with-forcondition-in-c

Comment: Sometimes I write `while 1+1=2 do` (Delphi syntax) just because it looks cool (and is very clear, intuitively). I suppose the optimizing compiler realizes that `1+1=2` is the constant expression `true`. :)

Comment: @gnovice: Those are not duplicates, they deal with implementation and performance; while this question opens up the debate for "style". This should be reopened.

Comment: @Jordão: The question just asks "which should I use?", but gives no criteria (style or performance). If the focus is performance, it's been covered before. If the focus is style, it's pretty subjective, and SO isn't really a place for such debate or discussion.

Comment: This is curious. Maybe the other ones should be closed, because this one is broader. But that's not how it works is it?

Comment: Let's say that I ask an even broader question: __"What are the ways and tradeoffs (performance, readability, etc) to implement infinite loops in C-style languages (C, C++, Java, C#, ...)?"__ Would that be deemed inappropriate and closed as well?

Answer (score 13):

In my opinion, `while(true)` is clearer.

Any half-decent compiler will compile both identically (at least with optimizations).
Therefore, you should choose whichever form you find clearer.

Comment: I thought so too, but some people here think that `for (;;)` is clearer. I was wondering why...

Comment: No idea.  Maybe they like that it's shorter.

Comment: It is sead that `for(;;)` should be read as `forever` but I find that you have to keep explaining that to people whereas `while(true)` is intuitively understood.

Comment: [Repeating a comment made at the answer from rmx] Before true/false was introduced, it was "while(1)" which is less obvious, and visually not that different from "while(i)". OTOH, "for(;;)" stands out visually. (After introducing the "true" keyword and with syntax-coloring, this argument has lost its validity)

Comment: `#define ever ;;`

Comment: I once saw a piece of code where the developer wrote "do while 1<>2", although I shouldn't have been surprised.  After all, the developer was using VB ;)

Comment: @baultista: that was a commented-out block of code in VB, which lacks a multiline comment construct. Very ugly indeed.

Answer (score 10):

```
for(;;)
```

has no obvious semantic value. Whereas

```
while(true)
```

could pretty much be understood by any reasonably intelligent non-programmer due to being far closer to the natural-language equivalent.

Comment: Before true/false was introduced, it was "while(1)" which is less obvious, and visually not that different from "while(i)". OTOH, "for(;;)" stands out visually. (After introducing the "true" keyword and with syntax-coloring, this argument has lost its validity).

Answer (score 4):

I prefer

```
do {
  // ....
} while(true);
```

It demotes the implementation choice for the infinite loop concept from the prominent place of the start of the loop.

If this is C++ or C, just create your own macro to abstract the concept better (in this case, the use of `while(TRUE)` or `for(;;)` is not that relevant):

```
#define forever for(;;)
```

This can be *somehow* adapted to C# too:

```
  forever: {
    // ...
    goto forever;
  }
```

(`goto` is not evil in this case)

Comment: "do { } while" is more difficult to read than "while { }" in my opinion, and should be avoided as much as possible

Comment: @gustavogb: Me too, it's just that for infinite loops I prefer `do {} while(true)`. But I'd have no problem using `while(true)` as well.

Answer (score 3):

In order of importance:

1. Whatever your current code style guide says
2. Whatever is in use in the current code
3. Whatever your manager prefers
4. Whatever your co-workers prefer
5. Whatever you prefer

Order of 3 and 4 could be reversed in some circumstances ;)

EDIT: I personally prefer "while (true)" (including space), but I seldomly arrive at point 5 in the list.

Comment: I have found before that manager's coding preferences must carry no weight.

Comment: @Joshua: They do carry some weight, as to what you should _not_ do....

Answer (score 2):

I prefer while(true) because I think it is more intuitive, elegant and philosophically interesting.

However it is ultimately just a matter of style.

Answer (score 2):

any decent developer will pass over both without getting confused. use whatever you feel like.

Answer (score 1):

A question I asked recently: [Difference between for(;;) and while (true) in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347477/difference-between-for-and-while-true-in-c)

Although mine was language specific, several of them expressed views on this very subject.

Personally, I prefer `while (true)` because I feel like `for (;;)` is leaving out almost necessary pieces. I'm a bit OCD about it, and I know they're not NECESSARY, but I feel that a `for` without parameters just looks incomplete. Obviously, there are situations where you don't want some of the parameters, but `while (true)` looks more syntactically complete to me in situations where a loop like this is warranted.

All in all, it's pretty moot (in a good way). Developers you work with should be able to understand that they're the same thing, and (at least in C# according to my question) they compile to the exact same thing. Anybody that complains because you did one instead of the other seems like they have their priorities a touch out of order.