# What does for (;;)  mean in Java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does for (;;) mean in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081339/what-does-for-mean-in-java)

I am reading some Java API docs, and I have encountered this loop of a very strange perky look, which elated me to come here and ask what is it about. Would be glad to find it as soon as possible. Thank you on your upcoming efforts.

```
  public int read() throws IOException {
       synchronized (lock) {
          ensureOpen();
           **for (;;)** {
               if (nextChar >= nChars) {
                  fill();
                  if (nextChar >= nChars)
                       return -1;
               }
              if (skipLF) {
                     skipLF = false;
                  if (cb[nextChar] == '\n') {
                     nextChar++;
                      continue;
                   }
               }
             return cb[nextChar++];
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: it is definitely duplicate, however while writing this Q. I couldn't find this answer, and it didn't pop up, while I was making my Q., which is you have to admit kinda odd. :D

Comment: You had to scroll down a bit ;) Anyways.... now we know :)

Answer (score 4):

> for(;;)

That is an infinite loop.

For example, it's equivalent to something like

> while(true)

[Naturally, to exit such a loop, a branching statement is used.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

EDIT: clearly the use of the word "infinite" was a bad choice. Still, for all intents and purposes, a `for(;;)` loop does not terminate using the same conditional mechanism of typical `for` loops. I believe this was the point of the question. The comments are just splitting hairs at this point.

Comment: `for (;;) break;` is not infinite loop

Comment: @amit, obviously a break changes things.

Comment: A `break`, `return`, or `throw` statements. The point is - an infinite loop is determined according to its content as well as its condition int `i = 0; while (i < 1) { } ` is an infinite loop, though the condition is not strictly `true`.

Comment: what is more clean code like? for(;;) or while(true) ?

Comment: @nexus, it doesn't matter, they are essentially equivalent and *probably* produce the same bytecode.

Comment: @amit _as written_ it's an infinite loop. Changing the question in response to an answer is pedantry.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(;;)
```

This is an infinte loop, no variables initialization, no condition to check, no incremental step ... only exits the loop when execute the "return" sentence inside conditions.

Common for loop:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < max ; i++)
```

Hope helps.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the condition of termination of the cycle is not expressed in the usual form.

The only ways to terminate the cycle are the two `return` statements.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @Tom, this is an infinite loop.
Uses of this in your program could be if you would like to execute something forever.

Comment: Again, It is not an infinite loop. there are two exit points in it.