# What does for(;;) do?

Tags: php, for-loop

I have to maintain a code, and came up with this:

```
for (;;) {
  //code
}
```

What would it do? I couldn't find documentation about it.

In a hunch I think it runs only once... but that would be useless...

Comment: It endlessly does nothing - unless you put something inside the `{}` that is

Comment: It's the same as a `while(true)`

Comment: @DavidWilkins Well; the endlessly part is correct of course, but I assume the `//code` part is 'something' being done. Endlessly. ;)

Comment: @Jorge Then there is some code within the loop that escapes.

Comment: @Jorge then there is obviously something inside the `{}`

Comment: For example, this would not loop endlessly: `for(;;) { break; }`

Comment: @AndrewBarber maybe, but `//code` is a comment and does nothing

Comment: @DavidWilkins hah! Correct! :)

Comment: Different language but same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081339/what-does-for-mean-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is an infinite loop, similar in function as:

```
while(true) 
{
}
```

Comment: The most scary part is that I think I am responsible for this... lol. Might be something of my newbie things

Comment: hah! Doesn't it suck when you look at code you wrote in the past, and are all like... WTF is this supposed to do? Or... uhhh... so I hear... ;)

Comment: Oh I think I know why I did it... because I am checking for errors inside, and when some error is found, I have to exit and do not check the other errors... but there should be a better less scary way

Answer (score 2):

Your code sample is an infinite loop. To terminate, the omitted code (`//code`) must exit the loop or the entire PHP script.

Answer (score 2):

It's a for loop without initialization parameters, no breaking conditions and no increments/decrements/whatever on each iteration - think of it like `for (nothing; nothing; nothing)`.

Unless you break it from the inside, it's going to run forever.

Answer (score 1):

For embedded code it is the main loop that does all the other sub process in a super loop scheme.