# Specific for loop syntax in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I've seen somewhere the following syntax :

```
int i = index;
for (; i < anArray.length();)
```

is it similar to a while loop ?

```
while(i < anArray.length()) { 
// some stuff }.
```

Thanks

Comment: Partially it is similar, but note, that `i` does not change there, so there's a risk to get an infinite loop.

Comment: Not really a duplicate, but take a look at the accepted answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081339/what-does-for-mean-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) :

```
for (initialization; termination;increment) {
    statement(s)
}
```

writing `for (; i < anArray.length();)` means that you don't initalize and increment anything. You'll only go out the for loop if  `i < anArray.length()`. So yes, it is the same but I would doubt the utility of a for loop in this case.

More information from the [same doc page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) :

> Notice how the code declares a variable within the initialization
>   expression. The scope of this variable extends from its declaration to
>   the end of the block governed by the for statement, so it can be used
>   in the termination and increment expressions as well. If the variable
>   that controls a for statement is not needed outside of the loop, it's
>   best to declare the variable in the initialization expression. The
>   names i, j, and k are often used to control for loops; declaring them
>   within the initialization expression limits their life span and
>   reduces errors.
>
> The three expressions of the for loop are optional; an infinite loop
>   can be created as follows:

```
// infinite loop
for ( ; ; ) {

    // your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the for-loop is mostly used to iterate through a container (An Iterator or whatnot) So if you have a container of objects and you wish to manage something on all of them, a for-loop is a good way to go.

The while-loop however is mostly used to repeat a block of code until a condition is true:

```
boolean succesful = false;
while(!succesful) // runs until condition is false
{
 if(connectionToInternetIsSuccesful)
   succesful = true;
}
```

so while (pun intended) the condition (in this case the "succesful" boolean) is false it repeats the loop 
I recommend reading this : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_loop_control.htm

Answer (score 0):

Yes. They are similar. They both do the same thing.