# Is it a good practice to put String.toCharArray() into for loop

Tags: java, string, char

I came across code like below several times:

```
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    ....
}
```

I'm wondering if `s.toCharArray()` only excuted once or excuted `s.length` times? And what about the case below?

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.toCharArray().length; i++) {
    ....
}
```

---

Inspired by comments, did some test:

Case 1: excution time : 692.664

```
    String s = "dfsdfjglsdlghsl";
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 25; i++){
        s += s;
    }
    long start_time = System.nanoTime();

    for(char c : s.toCharArray()){
        int i = 0;
    }

    long end_time = System.nanoTime();
    double excution_time = (end_time - start_time)/1e6;
    System.out.println(excution_time);
```

Case 2: excution time : 688.217

```
    String s = "dfsdfjglsdlghsl";
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 25; i++){
        s += s;
    }
    long start_time = System.nanoTime();

    char[] carrays = s.toCharArray();
    for(char c : carrays){
        int i = 0;
    }

    long end_time = System.nanoTime();
    double excution_time = (end_time - start_time)/1e6;
    System.out.println(excution_time);
```

Almost the same. So, `s.toCharArray()` should only be excuted once in the first case.

Comment: It's only executed once. You can find the equivalent basic for loop for the enhanced for loop [in JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) (search for "Otherwise, the Expression necessarily has an array type, T[].").

Comment: In your second example, `s.toCharArray().length` is invoked on each execution of the loop. That's unfortunate, because it copies the string into a new array each time, making this for loop at least quadratic in the string length. It's also functionally equivalent to the constant time expression `s.length()`; I'd recommend the latter.

Comment: +1 for Any's comment, which I suppose can be turned into an answer. My comment is: execute this in the debugger and set a breakpoint to observe Andy's claims.

Comment: And [how a regular for statement works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081339/how-does-a-for-loop-work-specifically-for).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [JLS Sec 14.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2), an enhanced for statement over an array type:

```
L1: L2: ... Lm:
for ({VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier : Expression) {
  Statement
}
```

is equivalent to the following basic for statement:

```
T[] #a = Expression;
L1: L2: ... Lm:
for (int #i = 0; #i < #a.length; #i++) {
    {VariableModifier} TargetType Identifier = #a[#i];
    Statement
}
```

So:

```
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
  // ...
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
T[] cs = s.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < cs.length; i++) {
    char c = cs[i];
    // ...
}
```

So the `s.toCharArray()` is executed only once.

However, in

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.toCharArray().length; i++) {
```

the `s.toCharArray()` is executed before every iteration of the loop. This is not desirable, since it creates a new array of length `s.length()`, copies the chars into that array, then takes the length of the array and discards the data.

Since the loop executes `s.length()` times, this loop is then at least quadratic in the string length.

It's much computationally cheaper to use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
```

which is linear in the string length.