# Regex to match for statement

Tags: regex

For a university task I need to match for loops from input with regex so I want to write a regex to recognize it.

I tried following regex but it doesn't match anything:

`for\((\w*\s+\w+\s*\=\s*\d+\s*)?\;(\s*\w+\s*\W+\d+\s*)\;(\s*\w+\W+)\)\{ . \}`

this is the regex I used.

```
for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){  
System.out.println(i);  
}
```

and this is something like what I want to match.

Comment: In which language are you trying to achieve this? You might better use a parser here.

Comment: `\{ . \}` seems wrong

Comment: You want the job of the parser to be done by a regex?

Comment: How will you parse nested for loops using regex?

Comment: Replace `\{ . \}` with `\{[\S\s]+\}`. However, be aware that this won't match any kind of a for loop.

Comment: Please don't use a regex to parse a complex language such as Java, especially when tons of parsers already exist for the language.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed tank you very much. this is a university task and I should implement it with regex. I think it is better to send your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As others have suggested, this is not a suitable task for regex; ***you
>   should use a parser***.

That being said, if you must use regex **and** you *only* care about matching a for loop ***in the exact format you provided***, you may replace the `\{ . \}` part with something like `\{[\S\s]+\}` in order to match the body successfully.

Here's the full pattern:

```regex
for\s*\((\w*\s+\w+\s*\=\s*\d+\s*)?\;(\s*\w+\s*\W+\d+\s*)?\;(\s*\w+\W+)?\)\s*\{[\S\s]+?\}
```

**[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ez91ky/1)**.

I made some additional changes to it. For example, allowed more whitespaces where appropriate and made the 2nd and 3rd groups optional, *since each of the initialization, the condition and the update (increment/decrement) [are indeed optional in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7081497/4934172)* and to match an infinite loop as well. Feel free to keep or disregard these changes based on your requirements.

**However,** as I said above, this focuses *only* on the format of the for loop provided in the question and it will *not* match every possible way to write a for loop as I previously mentioned in the comments. Some examples of those cases:

```java
// The update/increment may use a different operator.
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i += 1) { }

// The condition can be any expression that evaluates to boolean.
for (int i = 1; i * 2 <= 10; i++) { }

// A for loop can have no braces.
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)           
    System.out.println(i);

// Etc.
```