# Javascript: do while versus while

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, iteration, do-while

Is there any real difference between `do-while` loops and `while` loops in Javascript?
I know that `do-while` executes the code block before checking the condition, and `while` checks the condition first, but are there any other differences like performance?

Comment: In my opanion i don't think so that they have differences in performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you said `do-while` will execute the code block at least once even when the condition fails.

Other than **functional difference**, there should be **no** performance difference.

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745545/performance-difference-between-for-while-and-do-while-loop).