# what is the between in writing a loop by branching statement and a normal loop

Tags: c++, loops

what is the between in writing a loop by branching jump statement and a normal loop
i.e for example

```
        main()
        {
        int i=0;
        while(i<9)
        {
          //do something
           i++;
        }
```

and

```
        main()
        {
            int i=0;
            label:
             //do something
              i++;
             if(i<9)
              goto label;
         }
```

is the performance of both of them are equal?

Comment: The difference is that if you use the second one you'll get [run over by dinosaurs](http://xkcd.com/292/)

Comment: There's not branching here, since the code is not used. Use http://gcc.godbolt.org/ to see the assembler code.

Comment: Your label-Code is the equivalent for a do-while loop, not for a while loop.

Comment: Depends on the compiler. Also, `goto` is anathema.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366929/c-c-is-goto-faster-than-while-and-for

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the `goto` solution is *inferior* because it generates slightly different IR which is missed by some optimization passes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These two loops are not equivalent: the second one is similar to a `do`/`while` loop, not a `while` loop:

```
main() {
    int i=0;
    do {
      //do something
       i++;
    } while(i<9);
}
```

The two should be the same as far as the performance goes; however, the readability of the solution with the `goto` [suffers considerably](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/ewd02xx/EWD215.PDF), so I would refrain from using it in any of your projects.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that the first one is a lot easier to read, which is why `goto`  is generally avoided. Also as pointed out in [dasblinkenlight's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17108759/28169) the semantics are not the same.

The performance should be about the same, since the CPU has to do jumps in order to implement both. Of course, with a higher-level description of intent (as in the first case) the chance of the compiler being able to optimize something increases.

Perhaps not in this particular case, but in general a more high-level description of what you want to do is to be preferred, and then the looping constructs are better than `goto`.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, compiler should produce an equivalent output. But I don't think these two examples are equivalent - a `while` first checks the condition and then decides wheter to execute the body. Your example with the `goto` first executes the body and then checks the conditions - it behaves more like a `do while` statement.

You shouldn't use `goto` in this case, as it reduces readability. `goto`s are valid in only a limited number of scenarios.