# How do I make int main order reset

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    Kund KundObjekt;
    Meny MenyObjekt;
    Konto KontoObjekt;


    MenyObjekt.Meny1();
    KundObjekt.LoggaIn();
    MenyObjekt.Meny2(KundObjekt);
    if (menyval2 == 4) 
    {

    }
    KontoObjekt.PengarIn();
    KontoObjekt.PengarUt();
    KontoObjekt.VisaSaldo();
    return 0;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

How do I start at the top again if the if happens? Like `if menyval2 == 4` I want the next call to be `MenyObjekt.Meny1();` and then `KundObjekt.LoggaIn();` and so on.

Comment: Put it in a loop; this is well-explained in [every C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/636019) in existence. ;-]

Comment: or do bad practice and use goto:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `while()` loop, of course

```
while(menyval2 == 4)
{
    MenyObjekt.Meny1();
    KundObjekt.LoggaIn();
    MenyObjekt.Meny2(KundObjekt);
}
```

This loop will execute until the value stops being `4`

Alternatively, if your logic demands that the 3 lines are executed **regardless** of the initial value of `menyval2`, you can use the do-while loop, as suggested by João Castilho.

I'll repeat his code here, for clarity:

```
do{
    MenyObjekt.Meny1();
    KundObjekt.LoggaIn();
    MenyObjekt.Meny2(KundObjekt);
}while(menyval2 == 4);
```

Comment: I would have to make the default value int menyval2 = 4; right?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a do-while loop. In that case, the answer is

```
do{
    MenyObjekt.Meny1();
    KundObjekt.LoggaIn();
    MenyObjekt.Meny2(KundObjekt);
}while(menyval2 == 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use goto statement.
Eg:

```
int main
{
   int X;
   A : 
       X = 10;
       if ( X== 10)
       {
           goto A;
        }
return 0;
}
```

that is all,When it comes under if statement . it will reach the top of if statement.

Comment: whats better, goto or loop?

Comment: It's widely known that every time you use goto, a puppy dies, so I guess it depends whether you like puppies or not.

Comment: Here in this link you can find comparison between those two https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366929/c-c-is-goto-faster-than-while-and-for

Answer (score 0):

> How do I start at the top again if the if happens?

You might consider the following minor refactor:

```
int main2()
{
    Kund KundObjekt;
    Meny MenyObjekt;
    Konto KontoObjekt;

    MenyObjekt.Meny1();
    KundObjekt.LoggaIn();
    MenyObjekt.Meny2(KundObjekt);
    if (menyval2 == 4) 
    {
       main2();  // you can invoke main2()
    }
    KontoObjekt.PengarIn();
    KontoObjekt.PengarUt();
    KontoObjekt.VisaSaldo();
    return 0;
}

int main()  // no code you write should invoke 'main'
{
   return (main2());
   system("PAUSE");
}
```

The idea is simply that you are never constrained to work **within** main().

Also, you must remember that the function 'main()' is special.  Your code should never attempt to invoke it.

However, many of your peers won't like the recursion. For this to work, you will have to decide that the 'if-clause' is sufficient (to terminate the recursion).

On the other hand ...

---

Because you marked this as C++, you should consider using a class.

Using a class simplifies several issues.

For example, the functions f1() and f2() need no forward declare, nor is the order an issue.

Also, data attributes are available to all functions of the class instance, no need to pass values or be limited to the function scope where the data is declared.

```
class M2  
{
   private:
       Kund KundObjekt;
       Meny MenyObjekt;
       Konto KontoObjekt;       

   public:
       int exec()
       {
          do {   f1();  } while (menyval2 == 4); 
          f2();
          return(0);
       }

   private:  // note: no need to 'forward declare' for use in exec

      void f1() {
         MenyObjekt.Meny1();
         KundObjekt.LoggaIn();
         MenyObjekt.Meny2(KundObjekt);
      }

      void f2() {
        KontoObjekt.PengarIn();
        KontoObjekt.PengarUt();
        KontoObjekt.VisaSaldo();
      }
};

int main() 
{
   M2           m2;         // so create someplace to jump to
   int retVal = m2.exec();  // and do what you want there

   system("PAUSE");   
   return(retVal);
}
```

---

FYI - There exists a better mechanism than "system("PAUSE")".  A tool setting change I think.  Sorry, I do not know that tool.

Comment: That looks very over-engineered to my taste, TBH