# Possible to find whether a String array value equals any random typed string?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Let's say I got this array:

> String[][]array = new String[5][5];
>
> > array[2][2] = desperate;
>
> Would it be possible to find whether
>
> String s = "desperate"; - equals any array element without using a for loop, and without having to manually enter the row column combination of the array assigned the value "desperate"?

Comment: Out of curiosity: what do you need a two-dimensional array of strings for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use enhanced-for loop:  -

```
String [][] array = new String[2][2];
array[1][1] = "desperate";
array[0][1] = "despee";
array[1][0] = "despete";
array[0][0] = "dete";

for (String[] innerArr: array) {
    for (String value: innerArr) {
         if (value.equals("desperate")) {
             System.out.println(value + " == desperate");
         }
    }
}
```

Output: - **desperate == desperate**

A **better** way that I would suggest is to use `ArrayList<String>` to store your items.. Then you can just call `contains()` method to check whether the list contains that element..

```
List<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>(); 
listString.add("desperate");
listString.add("despe");

if (listString.contains("desperate")) {
     System.out.println("True");
}
```

Output: - **True**

Comment: In the enhanced for loop does (String[] innerArr: array) only search the row arrays?

Comment: Exactly.. Outer loop fetches you each row.. which is itself an array.. Now taking the variable(innerArr) from outer loop, we iterate over it to get each element..

Answer (score 3):

`while` loop instead of for loop

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;  
while (i < n)  
{  
   while (j < m)  
   {  
      if (array[i][j].equals("..."))
      {  
         /// 
      }  
      j++;
   }   
   i++;    
}
```

Comment: I don't think the style of loop is really the key to the question, and generally most people prefer for loops http://stackoverflow.com/q/3875114/106261

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can't (for any reasons) change your array to another collection type:

```
String[][]array = new String[5][5];
array[2][2] = "desperate"; 


public boolean contains(String str){
  return new HashSet<String>((List<String>)Arrays.asList(array)).contains(str);
}
```

Better than transforming it to a `List` since HashSet's `contains()` method is **O(1)** and the one from `List` is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

The only way to avoid using a loop (and it not clear why you would want to) is to use a Map which you pre-build with all the strings and indexes.